How can I store Postgres SUM results in multiple variables?
  DECLARE
    total1 float;
    total2 float;
  
  SELECT
      SUM(CASE WHEN totals.valid = 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END),
      SUM(CASE WHEN totals.valid <> 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END)
      INTO total1, total2
  FROM
    totals;

Here, Postgres informs me that I have an error in my condition's syntax :
ERROR:  42601: syntax error at end of input

LINE 12:       SUM(CASE WHEN totals.valid = 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END),

                                          ^

CONTEXT:  invalid type name "SUM(CASE WHEN totals.valid "

But when I remove the INTO total1, total2 statement the code runs perfectly fine. What's the problem here ?

Please create a [mre], see: https://dbfiddle.uk/U3qaPH-3 (which show I cannot reproduce your problem).


You're still in the declare section. The parser expects you to keep declaring variables until it hits a begin so it assumes you're trying to declare something named select and follow it with what type you want it to be. You get the error because sum(case.. isn't a valid type name.
It's not a good idea, but technically, you can define a PL/pgSQL variable named select.

Once you add the missing begin after declarations, the rest of your code is ok. That's exactly how you can store Postgres SUM results in multiple variables.

Use the aggregate filter clause.


Demo at db<>fiddle:
do $f$
  DECLARE
    total1 float;
    total2 float;
  BEGIN--this was missing
  SELECT
      SUM(amount)FILTER(WHERE totals.valid=0),
      SUM(amount)FILTER(WHERE totals.valid<>0)
  INTO total1, total2
  FROM
    totals;
end $f$;

